# Logging network tab automatically without opening it in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I need to log the information shown in network tab to a file. I can do it by firing network tab first and then exporting it to a file. But is it possible to run the network tab and exporting it to a file in the background automatically whenever the Chrome is opened?

Is it possible to do?

Comment: See chrome.debugger API. Your extension can attach to the tab and then use the protocol's [Network](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Network/) commands. I didn't read the entire protocol documentation so I don't see a way to save HAR and maybe you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: See also [node.js remote-debugging scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugging-clients#nodejs).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your requirement. If your extension involves DevTools, and therefore it is open, you can use the [`chrome.devtools.network.getHAR()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network#method-getHAR) method to get the network traffic. You don't need to navigate to the Network tab.

However, if you want to access the network data without DevTools being opened, this API will not work, as it's only exposed to the DevTools instance. There are a couple of possible options.

## Option 1

You could use the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API to intercept each request/response and append whatever data you want/can to an object. You could then use the [chrome.downloads](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) API to download the data. In your case, you could use a data URI.

```
var url = 'data:application/json;base64,' + btoa(data);
chrome.downloads.download({url: url, filename: 'notQuiteAHAR'json'});
```

I haven't tested this in practice, and I'm not too sure if you can determine when all requests are done before calling the download.

## Option 2

Use the more low level [`chrome.debugger`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/) API, as per the comment by @wOxxOm. The debugging protocol only allows one instance of the debugger at a time, so this will only ever work if you don't have DevTools running. The API exposes a lot more than the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API, but requires a bit of work to get all the data you need.

There's a repository called [`chrome-har-capturer`](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer), which uses the debugging protocol. Of particular interest is [`har.js`](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer/blob/master/lib/har.js), which uses the events found in the debugger API to manually construct the HAR. The purpose of the library is for remote debugging purposes, but I believe you can use the debugger API in an extension, and so you could probably use aspects of this repository.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Gideon Pyzer, [HAR Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/har-recorder/emfabjnfjiknifjlfpjobbecfepplhkd/) uses chrome debug protocol to record HAR and generate a har file (without opening devtools). If you want a variation, you can fork and make changes on it.